# ¿Como puedo en función de la variable muestre segun el numero puesto?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema y es que tengo un recuadro para introducir un numero y en función de eso el progama php tiene que hacer un fibonacci segun lo introducido pero el problema es que no se como hacerlo . Alguien me puede ayudar? Lo agradeceria mucho

```
<form action="funciones.php" method="post" name="myForm">
Introduce Numero<br>
  <input type="int" name="numero" value=" "><br>

<input type="radio" id="age1" name="fib" >
  <label for="age1">Fibonacci</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age2" name="Fac" >
  <label for="age2">Factorial</label><br>  
  <input type="radio" id="age3" name="Sumax" >
  <label for="age3">Suma xifres</label><br><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age4" name="Capicua" >
  <label for="age4">Capicua</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['fib'])){
    function fibonacci ($num){
        $numero=0;
        $j1=0;
        $j2=1;
        echo $j1.' '.$j2.'  ';
        while($numero < $num){
            $j3=$j2+$j1;
            echo $j3.' ';
            $j1=$j2;
            $j2=$j3;
            $numero=$numero + 1;
        }
        
    
    }
    fibonacci('fib');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando ejecutas la función tienes que pasar-le la variable que quieres que actue como $num. Tu código debería ser así.

```
<input type="radio" id="age1" name="fib" >
  <label for="age1">Fibonacci</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age2" name="Fac" >
  <label for="age2">Factorial</label><br>  
  <input type="radio" id="age3" name="Sumax" >
  <label for="age3">Suma xifres</label><br><br>
  <input type="radio" id="age4" name="Capicua" >
  <label for="age4">Capicua</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['fib'])){
    function fibonacci ($num){
        $numero=0;
        $j1=0;
        $j2=1;
        echo $j1.' '.$j2.'  ';
        while($numero < $num){
            $j3=$j2+$j1;
            echo $j3.' ';
            $j1=$j2;
            $j2=$j3;
            $numero=$numero + 1;
        }
        
    
    }
    fibonacci($_POST['fib']);
}
```

En este caso, la variable $_POST['fib'], hará la función de $num en tu función.

Siempre que especifiques la necesidad de una variable cuando construyas la función:

```
    function fibonacci ($num){
```

Le tendrás que dar un valor que ocupe esa función, en tu caso habías introducido:

```
fibonacci('fib');
```

Por lo tanto estabas pasando una string a tu función cuando debería ser un int.

Comment: Vale Muchas Gracias me ha funcionado :)